# Is landing gear-up against the regs?

Tags: faa-regulations, landing-gear, accident-statistics, ntsb

Typically, landing a plane gear-up results in costly damage, which easily triggers the NTSB reporting requirement. However, as a glider pilot I can easily see how landing a glider gear-up would cause no more damage to the plane than a grass stain.

And yet it seems to me that landing gear-up is a somewhat egregious pilot error,  about which the FAA and my insurance company might eventually like to know. If for no other reason, the FAA/NTSB probably have a vested interest in tracking if gear-up prevention techniques are working.

Comment: Or maybe not. If I draw an analogy to cars, if I have a million little fender-benders getting my car in and out of the garage, that's surely no one's business but my own.

Comment: Landing gear up unintentionally is what’s called a “self punishing act”.  Illegal or not, why add insult to injury?

Comment: By the way, a typical gear-up general aviation landing in a part 91 operation would not result in NTSB involvement. See the link to part 830 with specific reference and definitions of what constitutes an "aircraft accident," what constitutes "serious injury" and what constitutes "substantial damage."  https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-49/subtitle-B/chapter-VIII/part-830

Comment: @KennSebesta: Two words - "metal fatigue".

Comment: Has this happened unintentionally on a commercial airliner? Are they supposed to be down when you ditch or land in a corn field?

Comment: Half asleep, for a few seconds I understood the title as landing the aircraft with the gear pointing upwards to the sky.

Comment: Your comment/analogy above regarding fender-benders and your garage does not fall within a potential violation of 91.13 (a). That regulation,  in order to apply, requires that someone else owns the car/garage and/or you have a passenger with you (or someone you endanger is in the garage).  Does not apply if you're solo in your car and it's your garage.

Comment: @Mazura Usually they should be up if you're ditching or landing in a corn field. In any case, you should be covered by 14 CFR 91.3 (b). Unless you're ditching or landing in a corn field for fun, in which case you probably have bigger problems.

Comment: **Please clarify** - is the gear-up landing by mistake, presumably an oversight,  and not an intentional choice as a result of equipment failure or other emergency?

Comment: @Criggie I'm asking about mistakes on public runways.

Comment: Note that you can reverse downvotes within 5 minutes, or if the answer has been edited since you voted.  For most viewers the chosen answer will be at the top.

Comment: Why would landing an aircraft be difference from parking a car, except in degree?

Where might it be written that a mistake is a crime?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin it's not a crime, per se, but it turns out that it is against the regs, as per FAR 91.13.

Comment: Sorry Kenn; I just don't follow how a mistake can't be allowed… unless the suggestion is that this mistake is too serious to forgive. Is that it?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin 757toga and Pondlife both give concrete examples of how it is against the regulations. Whether it's allowed or not is another matter.

Comment: “Allowed” versus choosing to prosecute are different things.  As I commented above, it’s a self punishing act, so why pile on?

Comment: @MichaelHall: The self-punishing act only results in a violation when a passenger(s) and/or owner of the aircraft (if not the pilot) is potentially endangered. When the pilot fails to complete the checklist (the gear down item) and in doing so puts the passenger or someone else property at risk, that carelessness is viewed as below the standard of care required from holder of a pilot certificate.  If no one else's safety or property is put at risk then perhaps it is only a "self" punishing action.

Comment: What I meant is the the pilot suffers either way.  If your passenger is injured you will be responsible for medical bills.  Damage a rental, you cover the repair cost.  (Or your insurance covers things, and your rates skyrocket.). If an otherwise decent pilot makes a one time flub when stuff is hitting the fan inflight are you espousing that the FAA revoke their pilot certificate?

Comment: @MichaelHall: of course not. I'm just passing along what I believe is the reasoning behind how and why the regulation is applied the way it is.  Not taking a personal position.

Comment: @KennSebesta Sorry; can you explain how what's "against the regulations" being "allowed" could be another matter?

If you insist that some mistakes are too serious to be forgiven, why not just say so?

Otherwise, why not accept that mistakes are… uh… mistakes?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin there's an entire study of "insincere rules", that is to say actions against the regs but still permitted. For an example of a widely held "insincere rule" in the US,  see the description of automotive speeding on Page 509 of https://deliverypdf.ssrn.com/delivery.php?ID=331005097121007071076001077110103090117046093006002049011113031091078001124068028002000030020015104116044126067021099001117004041026000040040118083024090003097088051054085086092071023124072114071091020090076107079012030121065025120084093116020119003&EXT=pdf&INDEX=TRUE

Comment: Hey Kenn, why not ask your lawyer, or insurer, or local FAA office?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I'm not sure what further problem that would solve, since the authoritative answer was already given by 757toga. If you want to discuss this more, let's continue in chat, https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=aviation.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Landing an aircraft gear up would likely result in a violation of 14 CFR 91.13 (a) - [FAR 91.13 - Careless or Reckless Operation](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.13) *unless you are the owner of the aircraft and no one else is on board*.

Endangering the life and/or property of someone else can be viewed as operating "...below the standard of care expected of a reasonable pilot in the same or similar circumstances...," according to the verbiage in the chart in the  first image shown below.

> 91.13 Careless or reckless operation.
>
> > (a) Aircraft operations for the purpose of air navigation. No person may operate an aircraft in a careless or reckless manner so as to **endanger the life or property of another**.
> > (emphasis is mine)

The image below is from page 4-15 of [FAA Order 2150.3C - Compliance and Enforcement Program](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/FAA_Order_2150.3C_CHG_7.pdf) showing the elements of a violation of FAR 91.13 (a), showing, as an example, a **gear-up landing** (highlighted in yellow).

[image]

Also note on page 9-22 of FAA Order 2150.3C (image below) a "Wheels up landing" is considered an "Independent Violation" (no other regulation needs to be violated).

[image]

Comment: Why would ownership be a factor?

Comment: @MichaelHall: because of the wording of 91.13 (a)  "...property of another." If it's your aircraft and no one else is on board 91.13 would not apply). (Unless the gear up landing made the aircraft slide into something or someone not on the aircraft...typically unlikely)

Comment: The operative word is careless or reckless.  A normal gear up landing which usually happens because someone was distracted by a secondary event, doesn't really meet that standard.  Unless the FAA is way more punitive than I imagined.... that's nuts.

Comment: @JohnK: I think that it's normally considered "careless" (and resulting in a violation of the FAR's) because ensuring the landing gear is down is a specific item on the aircraft's checklist. So, failure to use or follow the checklist is considered below the standard of care expected of a pilot (in spite of any distractions).

Comment: That assumes a level of infallibility that a even normal careful pilot can't be expected to achieve when things go out of the ordinary. The old saying is every pilot has either landed wheels up or is going to.That C.F.R. is only going to be applied if the investigator found that things went beyond a "good faith" error (like forgetting a checklist item because of a distraction - it's easy to do if you are mentally loaded enough),say by not using a checklist at all. Punishing pilots for doing their best but screwing up is the way things are done in China; it fosters covering up your mistakes.

Comment: @JohnK: I'm not advocating a position on the question, only researching and providing the information I find.

Comment: Understood. Just filling out the arguments for other viewers.

Comment: Interesting viewpoint. Regarding the question of whether there is only on person aboard or not, it's easy to argue that a glider disabled on the runway is a serious risk to the life and property of other glider pilots: as a result of a gear-up landing, the runway is rendered unsafe however other landing gliders have no ability to delay their landing or head to a safe alternate.

Comment: @KennSebesta: Also, "serious risk" is not the threshold/standard; it only requires "potential endangerment" to result in a violation of 91.13 (a).

Comment: @757toga Page 9-22 of FAA ORder 2150.3C specifically details Wheels Up Landing as a "Careless or Reckless Operation (Independent Violation) " of Severity 1. Thanks for the link, that pretty much seals the deal.

Comment: I'm convinced also, and deleted my post.  Perhaps the debate is really over whether the "illegal" action involves only administrative punishment or criminal liability.

Comment: @JohnK Upvoting your comment. I think my title is more provocative than I like, but I can't figure out wording which isn't and yet still retains its simplicity. Definitely open to suggestions.

Comment: Is it possible for the wheels-up landing to damage the runway? That would restrict non-violations to people who own both the aircraft *and the runway*, which is a much smaller subset.

Comment: @KRyan:interesting point. I suppose there would be some damage (even slight) with every gear up landing.

Answer (score 7):

During my 5 years being involved with gliding, landing gear up was a relatively common occurrence, either because the pilot somehow forgot to extend it, the gear got stuck or wasn't locked properly in place before touchdown. As long as there was no damage to the aircraft, the aircraft was simply lifted up, checked over by an appointed club MX inspector and released to service again. No report needed filing. If however the aircraft sustained damage or the gear had not extended due to a mechanical failure, that would indeed trigger a report as well as a visit from an "NTSB" investigator. (although this was all EASA / club-regime)

In regards to the insurance, most aircraft insurances will cover damage caused by accidental wrongful operation of the aircraft provided that the pilot was training and checked out according to all standards. If however the occurrence is categorized as the product of gross negligence and carelessness from the pilot, that is an other story.

I can't count the amount of material damage to aircraft and vehicles that was caused in my gliding club because people mishandled material and or made simple mistakes, so as long as it is not intentional, the insurance and no-blame culture will usually have your back... although you premium may rise considerably if it keeps happening.

Comment: Another good way to do this is to forget to raise the gear on release, fly round all day wondering why your L/D is so poor, then move the gear handle when you enter the pattern.  You can't see the wheel, of course, and some gliders have the gear lever working in different directions.  My instructor had us prepare per-glider checklists with 'Gear lever FORWARD' rather than 'DOWN' for this reason.

Answer (score 6):

The FAA has sanctioned pilots for landing gear up, as a violation of 91.13 (careless and reckless).

For example, a case from 2006: [Administrator vs. Lorenz, NTSB Order No. EA-5205](https://www.ntsb.gov/legal/alj/OnODocuments/Aviation/5205.PDF). There was only minor damage to the aircraft, and no damage to anyone else or anyone else's property. The pilot appealed to the NTSB, arguing that since there was no "potential endangerment" there was no violation. The NTSB upheld the FAA's position and the pilot lost.

Here are a few key points (the case has more details and references to other, previous cases):

> In particular, respondent, who holds a commercial pilot’s license,
> admits that on March 23, 2004, he inadvertently landed a Beechcraft
> Model V-35B at the Eastern Iowa Airport with the landing gear
> retracted. The aircraft sustained “minor” damage, and no other
> property was damaged.

> Landing an aircraft with the landing gear retracted clearly creates
> the potential for injury, death or significant property damage, not
> only to the aircraft and those aboard it, but to those persons or
> property that are, or reasonably could have been, in the vicinity of
> the runway.

Interestingly, the NTSB appears to say that who owns the aircraft is irrelevant, because even if it belonged to the pilot there's still "potential" danger to others who might be nearby:

> We need not address respondent’s arguments regarding the aircraft’s
> corporate ownership and whether it constitutes “property of another”
> in light of our finding that his gear-up landing created potential
> endangerment to other persons or property in the vicinity of the
> accident.

Per an [AOPA article](https://pilot-protection-services.aopa.org/news/2017/june/01/careless-or-reckless-operation), it's unusual for the FAA to pursue a 91.13 case for a gear-up landing:

> While there are a few of these cases on the books, our experience has
> shown that the FAA does not usually choose to take enforcement action
> in these situations, choosing instead to handle the matter
> administratively with a reexamination request or remedial training in
> order to be sure the pilot has the proper procedures in place to
> prevent a recurrence.

Perhaps in the case of Lorenz, there was more context or other factors that made the FAA bring the case. I couldn't find any more details about it.

Comment: Good info, thanks for the research.  I believe however,  that the overwhelming number of gear up landing violations remain solely within the FAA and are never appealed to the NTSB. So, it's hard to determine how many gear up landing cases don't lead to a 91.13 violation. (Mostly "careless" vs "reckless.")